# What HTML editors have this feature?

Tags: html, html-table, editor

I need a GUI HTML editor that I can use with Sphinx to produce tables that are more complex than reStructuredText supports. To be useful, the editor must have strong table editing capability, and also must be able to write an HTML file that begins with <table> and ends with </table>, rather than a complete loadable HTML file.

The problem is, I don't know what this feature is called. I think of it as "writing HTML snippets," but at least one major editor uses "snippet" in a completely different sense. What should I look for? Or alternately, what editors should I look at?

Comment: You can [convert csv to html table](https://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-html.htm) or are you looking for a tool like [a spreadsheet editor](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/html_tables)?

Comment: I'm sorry, I think you misunderstood my question. This has nothing to do with CSV or spreadsheets. I need a GUI editor that will let me compose a table, then will write HTML that consists of `<table>... </table>` instead of `<html> <head>... </head> <body> <table>... </table> </body> </html>`. That file will be incorporated into a restructuredText document with an `include` directive.

Comment: html tables are very spreadsheet-like, it's been a long time since people used tables for page layouts. Can you specify what kinds of tables are you trying to create, how would they look like, and what are the tools the GUI editor should have?

Comment: When I said "tables," I did not mean it in the technical HTML sense. I meant it in the sense that any reader would understand: collections of rows and columns containing information. Some tables will have font and face changes, solid color backgrounds, and cells that span rows and/or columns. It would be nice, but not essential, if text in certain header cells could be rotated 90 degrees clockwise.

Comment: One other thing: It's almost-but-not-quite essential for tables to adjust column widths automatically as the width of the window changes.

Answer (score 0):

Atom or Visual Studio Code will work nicely.

Comment: This answer doesn't quite answer the question, I would suggest including some atom/vscode extensions that would provide a way to edit tables visually which is what the question is asking.

Comment: I don't know Atom, but I use VS Code. Again, I fear I did not describe my need clearly and it was misunderstood. I'm looking for an editor with a GUI interface for _editing_ HTML, not just for previewing manually written code. I know of no VS Code extensions that do this -- I'm not convinced it's even possible. /// HTML preview would be better than nothing, so I second Yi Fan Song's request: if you don't know of a _GUI HTML editor_, which of the dozens or hundreds of available VS Code extensions would you recommend?